# Django session lost data (empty)

Tags: django, session-cookies

I want to use sessions in my site. I set the follwing setting in the settings.py file:

```
 'django.contrib.sessions', #in the installed apps
```

and

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
```

and

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', # in the midlleware classes
```

## view code

```
def apartamente(request):
    form = SearchFormApartamente()
    execute_form_process = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchFormApartamente(request.POST)
        execute_form_process = 1
        request.session['apartamente'] = form
        request.session['vasea'] = True
        request.session.set_expiry(300)
        request.session.modified = True
    elif 'apartamente' in request.session:
        form = searchFormApartamente(request.session['apartamente'])
        execute_form_process = 1

# forms.py
class SearchFormApartamente(forms.Form):
    thewidget = ColumnCheckboxSelectMultiple()
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Categorie_Oferta.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4]),
        required=False)
    sector = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Sector.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    min_price = forms.IntegerField(required=False,
        widget=forms.widgets.Input(attrs={'class': 'rounded'}))
    max_price = forms.DecimalField(required=False)
```

but, the problem is that I try to store a form in the session, and when I enter the view second time and try to read value from sessiom, the session is empty...
What can be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post your view code?

Comment: To get the session you must put `get` in `request.session.get('apartamente')` not this `request.session['apartamente']` because this format use for storing. Overall @Brandon answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-write the view code as shown below, assuming that `apartamente` is a field on the form.

```
# I know it doesn't affect scoping, but I don't like having the view name
# the same as a model or anything else for sanity

def apartamente_view(request):
    apartamente = request.session.get('apartamente', None)
    form = SearchFormApartamente(request.POST or None,
        initial={'apartamente': apartamente})

    execute_form_process = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            execute_form_process = 1
            request.session['apartamente'] = form.cleaned_data['apartamente']
            request.session['vasea'] = True
            request.session.set_expiry(300)

            # do you really need this?
            request.session.modified = True
            ...
```

Comment: I used
"request.session.modified" = True just to try to force save... But I also thing that is is not necessary there...

Comment: this code raise errors: in fact, the second line (form = ...): _init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'

Comment: Can you please add your form class to your code sample in the question?

Comment: class SearchFormApartamente(forms.Form):
thewidget = ColumnCheckboxSelectMultiple()
category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categorie_Oferta.objects.filter(Q(id = 1) | Q(id = 2) | Q(id = 3) | Q(id = 4)),
required=False)
    sector = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Sector.objects.all(), widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    min_price = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.widgets.Input(attrs={'class': 'rounded' }))
    max_price = forms.DecimalField(required=False }))
(can you tell me how you add code in comments? Because I try but...

Comment: See my updated answer to get around the `data` attribute problem.

Comment: No... the session is empty... :( . So, my work scenario is following: the form is used to set search criteria, and get some pages of data, then, I try to navigate to second page, and... (when I try to read apartamente from session, I get nothing...

Comment: Remove: `request.session.set_expiry(300)` and `request.session.modified = True` and try it.

Comment: I removed these lines, but the result is the same... :(

Comment: And you've tested to see whether or not your form is in fact valid and the code to set the session is being reached?

Comment: Yes. I debugged the code! And the form is valid! And I've created a watches and I sow there the session content. And the form is stored there, but when I enter again the view -> the session is empty

Comment: Dude - exclamation points aren't necessary. You're asking for help, I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Have you verified that other values are able to be stored in session? Do you perhaps accidentally have cookies disabled? Have you tried another session backend?

Comment: Excuse me for exclamation... I apreciate your intention to help me. Thank you very much for that, Brandon. I think the same that sometiong wrong in the settings or something like that. This was the reason why I posted the settings around the sessions...

Comment: No problem. My suggestion is this...unit test the hell out of this to determine what the problem is. It sounds like there's something wrong with the settings. I've used the code in my example many times before. I don't typically used signed cookies, so I would start there in my testing.